# TikZ: add the rotation arms of a Roulette Wheel

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I add a thing in the middle like this

[image]

here

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny\sffamily, thin]
% Roulette Wheel
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\s{36}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{1.7}% Outer Radius Number
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.4}% Inner Radius Number
\pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{0.5*(\R+\r)}% Fill-Radius Number
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\LW{1cm*(\R-\r)}% Line Width of Fill
\pgfmathsetmacro\rT{1.0}% Inner Radius Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\rA{2.3}% Outer Radius Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\rD{0.5*(\rA+\R)-0.025}% Radius of Diamonds
\pgfmathsetmacro\wM{360/(\s+1)}% Middle Point Angle
% List of Numbers
\def\RLT{0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26}
% Array of List
\def\RLTa{{\RLT}}

\foreach \Place in {0,...,\s}{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStart{90-0.5*\wM-\Place*\wM}% Startangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEnd{\wStart+\wM}% Endangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\wMiddle{\wStart+0.5*\wM)}% 
% Fill Number Areas
\pgfmathsetmacro\rscolor{mod(\Place,2)==0 ? 1 : 0}
\ifnum\Place=0 \colorlet{rscolor}{green!66!black} \else%
  \ifnum\rscolor=1 \colorlet{rscolor}{black} \else \colorlet{rscolor}{red}%
\fi\fi%
\path[draw=rscolor, line width=\LW,
] ([shift=(\wStart:\Radius)]0,0) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\Radius]; 
% Write Numbers
\path[draw=none] (\wMiddle:\r) -- (\wMiddle:\R) node[inner sep=0pt, midway, 
rotate={-\Place*\wM}, text=white, 
]{\pgfmathprint{\RLTa[\Place]}};
% Poches 
\draw[] (\wStart:\rT) -- (\wStart:\R);
}%%

% Circles
\draw[] circle[radius=\R];
\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
\draw[] circle[radius=\rT];
\draw[double,double distance=0.4pt] circle[radius=\rA];
% Diamonds
\foreach \w in {60, 120,...,360}{%%
\node[shape=diamond, draw, inner sep=0pt,
minimum width=1mm, minimum height=2.5mm, very thin, rotate=\w,
] at (\w:\rD){};
}%%
\foreach \w in {30, 90,...,330}{%%
\node[shape=diamond, draw, inner sep=0pt, 
minimum width=2mm, minimum height=1mm, very thin, rotate=\w,
] at (\w:\rD){};
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I took the liberty of simplify a bit your code, adding a couple of styles and a `\pic` for the slots.

I'm drawing a simpler version of the arms too, I hope it helps. A trapezium and a circle for each arm repeated and rotated with a `\foreach` loop, and a couple of circles on top of that. They have a parameter for its rotation, that you can change if you want.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset
{% slots styles
   fill0/.style={fill=green!66!black},
   fill1/.style={fill=black},
   fill2/.style={fill=red},
 % diamond style
   my diamond/.style={shape=diamond,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1mm,minimum height=2.5mm,very thin},
 % slot
   pics/slot/.style n args={3}{code=
   {% #1 = inner radius, #2 = outer radius, #3 = node
      \draw[pic actions] (-0.5*\slotangle:#1) arc (-0.5*\slotangle:0.5*\slotangle:#1) --
                          (0.5*\slotangle:#2) arc (0.5*\slotangle:-0.5*\slotangle:#2) -- cycle;
      \node[transform shape,white,rotate=-90] (-n) at (0:0.5*#1+0.5*#2) {#3};
   }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny\sffamily]
% Roulette Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\slotangle{360/37}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R {1.7} % Outer Radius Number
\pgfmathsetmacro\r {1.4} % Inner Radius Number
\pgfmathsetmacro\rT{1.0} % Inner Radius Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\rA{2.3} % Outer Radius Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\rD{0.5*(\rA+\R)-0.025} % Radius of Diamonds
% Circle
\draw[double,double distance=0.4pt] circle[radius=\rA];
% Diamonds
\foreach \w in {30,60,...,360}
  \node[my diamond,rotate={\w-3*mod(\w,60)}] at (\w:\rD) {};
% Slots
\foreach[count=\ii from 0]\i in {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,
                                 36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,
                                 31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\stn{\ii==0 ? 0 : int(mod(\ii,2)+1)} % slot style
  \pic[rotate=90-\slotangle*\ii,fill\stn]  {slot={\r}{\R}{\i}};
  \pic[rotate=90-\slotangle*\ii] (\i)      {slot={\rT}{\r}{}};
}
% Arms
\pgfmathsetmacro\rt{30} % rotation
\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
{
  \draw[rotate=\i+\rt,fill=gray] (0,0.1) -- (0.7,0.05) -- (0.7,-0.05) -- (0,-0.1) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray!30!black]      (\i+\rt:0.7) circle (0.1);
}
\draw[fill=gray!50!black] (0,0) circle(0.2);
\draw[fill=gray]          (0,0) circle(0.1);
% Ball
\draw[shading=ball,ball color=yellow,very thin] (23-n) circle (0.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And, you can try your luck here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not that well constructed but looks a bit more like the fotograph:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny\sffamily, thin]
% Roulette Wheel
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\s{36}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{1.7}% Outer Radius Number
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{1.4}% Inner Radius Number
\pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{0.5*(\R+\r)}% Fill-Radius Number
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\LW{1cm*(\R-\r)}% Line Width of Fill
\pgfmathsetmacro\rT{1.0}% Inner Radius Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\rA{2.3}% Outer Radius Wheel
\pgfmathsetmacro\rD{0.5*(\rA+\R)-0.025}% Radius of Diamonds
\pgfmathsetmacro\wM{360/(\s+1)}% Middle Point Angle
% List of Numbers
\def\RLT{0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26}
% Array of List
\def\RLTa{{\RLT}}

\foreach \Place in {0,...,\s}{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStart{90-0.5*\wM-\Place*\wM}% Startangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEnd{\wStart+\wM}% Endangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\wMiddle{\wStart+0.5*\wM)}% 
% Fill Number Areas
\pgfmathsetmacro\rscolor{mod(\Place,2)==0 ? 1 : 0}
\ifnum\Place=0 \colorlet{rscolor}{green!66!black} \else%
  \ifnum\rscolor=1 \colorlet{rscolor}{black} \else \colorlet{rscolor}{red}%
\fi\fi%
\path[draw=rscolor, line width=\LW,
] ([shift=(\wStart:\Radius)]0,0) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\Radius]; 
% Write Numbers
\path[draw=none] (\wMiddle:\r) -- (\wMiddle:\R) node[inner sep=0pt, midway, 
rotate={-\Place*\wM}, text=white, 
]{\pgfmathprint{\RLTa[\Place]}};
% Poches 
\draw[] (\wStart:\rT) -- (\wStart:\R);
}%%

% Circles
\draw[] circle[radius=\R];
\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
\draw[] circle[radius=\rT];
\draw[double,double distance=0.4pt] circle[radius=\rA];
% Diamonds
\foreach \w in {60, 120,...,360}{%%
\node[shape=diamond, draw, inner sep=0pt,
minimum width=1mm, minimum height=2.5mm, very thin, rotate=\w,
] at (\w:\rD){};
}%%
\foreach \w in {30, 90,...,330}{%%
\node[shape=diamond, draw, inner sep=0pt, 
minimum width=2mm, minimum height=1mm, very thin, rotate=\w,
] at (\w:\rD){};
}%%

% Rotating Arms
\foreach \w in {-45, 45, 135, -135}{%%
\begin{scope}[rotate=\w]
\draw[fill=white, rounded corners=0.25mm] (-0.05, 0.2) 
-- (-0.05, 0.4) 
-- ++(135:0.05)
 -- ++(45:0.05)
 -- ++(100:0.15)
 -- ++(80:0.15)
-- ++(135:0.05)
-- ++(45:0.05) % ------------
-- ++(0.1,0)
-- ++(-45:0.05)
-- ++(135+90:0.05)
 -- ++(-80:0.15)
 -- ++(-100:0.15)
-- ++(-45:0.05)
-- ++(135+90:0.05)
-- ++(0, -0.2) -- cycle;
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStart{-135}% Startangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEnd{\wStart-360+90}% Endangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{0.075}% Fill-Radius Number
\path[, draw,fill=white, 
] ([shift=(\wStart:\Radius)]0,0.875) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\Radius]; 
\end{scope}
}%%
\begin{scope}[]
\draw[fill=white] circle[radius=0.225];
\draw[] circle[radius=0.125];
\draw[] circle[radius=0.075];
%\draw[] circle[radius=0.05];% only arc

\pgfmathsetmacro\wStart{220}% Startangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEnd{\wStart-170}% Endangle
\pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{0.05}% Fill-Radius Number
\path[draw,  
] ([shift=(\wStart:\Radius)]0,0) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\Radius]; 
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```